# Why I'm getting “org.apache.catalina.connector.ClientAbortException: java.io.IOException: Connection reset by peer”?

Tags: networking, amazon-web-services, tomcat

All of sudden from production I'm receiving above error which I'm not sure from where it is coming. So I pulled the deployed code and connected it to live db just to check on my local-host if I do get the same error. But on local-host everything is working fine. Now I'm not sure what is causing this error and how to solve this for production.

Comment: This error means that client has aborted connection. In common case server should filter off this error from logging.